# Problem with onchange and jQuery val() and text()

Tags: jquery

i have an text area like this one which i write in it now
now i want when onchange the textarea content appear in a pre
i used

```
<textarea id="content" onchange="perview();"></textarea>


function perview() {
var code = $("textarea#content").val();
$('#code-preview').html(code);
}
```

i think every thing is ok

```
<pre id="code-preview"></pre>
```

but when using highlighter on the pre its not working
like that

```
<pre id="code-preview" class="brush: php;"></pre>
```

the SyntaxHighlighter
version 2.1.364 (October 15 2009)

Comment: What exactly means *its not working like that* ? Does it work without the highlighter? I assume, the highlighter only processes the `<pre>` tags on page load.

Comment: `class="brush: php;"` isn't right at all. `class` is for a list of whitespace-separated class names, yours looks like it belongs more in the `style` attribute.

Comment: no the highlighter working great but when change the text its not changed in highlighter

Answer (score 1):

have you tried,

```
function perview() {
   var code = $("textarea#content").val();
    $('#code-preview').html(code);
    SyntaxHighlighter.all() // <--- calling this again...
}
```

that is if we are using same [highligher](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:Usage). if that works, please try not inline events.. ;) cheers...

Answer (score 0):

instead of using onchange="" try using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('textarea#content').change(function(){
          var code = $(this).val();
          $('#code-preview').html(code);
     });
});
```

you may also want to try a few other things such as .blur() instad of .change().

also remove the ; from your class.  that should read:

```
<pre id="code-preview" class="brush:php"></pre>
```

I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: what's with the negative vote?  if it's about the class fix, so you know it's actually part of a plugin that he's using called syntax highlighter which requires you used class="brush:php" or brush:js and so on and so on.

here's the examples:
http://www.lastengine.com/syntax-highlighter-wordpress-plugin/#usage